# Saving arrays of float in a .txt file in columns

Tags: python, arrays, txt

I have 15 arrays of float (130 x 150) each, called (a,b,c,d,..,q).
And I would like to save these to a .txt file called array.txt.
The format should be 15 columns for 19500 rows, where array a occupy the entire first column, b the second etc..
The elements from each array should be picked rows by rows.

Can someone help me with this? How can I do it? I was thinking with 15 for loops for each element of the arrays, but I think that is not smart and better methods are possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably easiest to use pandas and save as csv, then you can convert to txt if you really wanted.

Comment: Why 15 loops? Your array is two-dimensional, not 15-dimensional

Comment: @MarcusMüller I was thinking a loop for each array

Comment: Also, friendly reminder that saving numerical data as text is not only inefficient in both space and time, but also leads to rounding errors, which have fundamentally changed the result of more than one simulation. (Same for saved weights from brutal networks, by the way) you seem to be dealing with more numerical data than a human could read, anyways, so don't use textual storage.

Comment: A loop per array makes no sense, either. It's a 1D set of arrays.

Comment: Why saving floating point numbers as text is bad is nicely illustrated by the [history of chaos theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory#History) (compare the paragraph on Lorenz' weather simulation printout to yours)

Comment: @MarcusMüller you are right thanks. 
But I need this .txt file for another software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,10]
c = [11,12,13,14,15]
l = zip(a,b,c)
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["a","b","c"])
np.savetxt(r'array.txt', df.values, fmt='%f')
```

This will combine the lists "a","b" and "c" and write them to a text file named array.txt

Answer (score 0):

I too would normally recommend using Pandas for these operations, but if you are required to use Numpy, you could try something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Set up dummy-problem
data = {key: np.random.random((130, 150)) for key in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ"}
# You would probably create a list containing the variables [a, b, c, ..., q]

# Concatenate results and save data
result = np.concatenate([a.flatten("F")[:, None] for a in data.values()], axis=1)
np.savetxt("data.txt", result)

# PS! To read as a Pandas DataFrame, use
pd.DataFrame({key: a.flatten("F") for key, a in data.items()})
```